# How to find and replace an <img src> tag?

Tags: image

I have `<img src="/path/file-to-be-replaced.png">` in a Single-Line Text Type in a Table Field Type which is inside a matrix. Now I want to replace all of them through `Find and replace` option. But when I use `<img src="/path/file-to-be-replaced.png">` and `Yes` in Find and Replace Fields respectively then nowhere it is replaced. However a task runs saying `Replacing “<img src="/path/file-to-be-replaced.png" />” with “Yes”` but still nothing happens.

Could anyone please help.

Comment: I guess this might be because `<img src="/path/file-to-be-replaced.png">` must be storing in some other format in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Find and Replace tool only works with "textual" field types (i.e. Plain Text and Rich Text fields).  Table fields store their content JSON encoded in the database so the tool ignores it.

Comment: Thank You for the information. Just a quick question, Is there an easy way of doing above task rather then manually changing it one by one ?

Comment: Sure... could be done with a one-off PHP script or simple Craft plugin doing exactly what you need it to.